# Apple Watch 1D Barcode in Apple Wallet not visible

Tags: ios, apple-watch, passbook, wallet

Since Wallet is supporting `Code128` since iOS9.

I am generating barcodes a Code128 barcode in my app and allow to push them into Apple Wallet.
Works perfectly fine in the wallet app on the smartphone (`Code128` barcode correctly displayed).

Unfortunately, the Wallet app on the Apple Watch doesn't show any barcode in the pass (pass exists though).

Is it necessary to perform additional steps to make passes with `Code128` Barcode compatible to Apple Watch?

Comment: Sounds like a Watch OS bug, especially if your fallback code is not appearing.  There should be no further steps required.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same thing. A blank pass on the Watch; barcode shows on phone. Also Code128.

Comment: FWIW, PKBarcodeFormatQR and PKBarcodeFormatPDF417 do display.

Answer (score 0):

`PKBarcodeFormatCode128` is not supported by watchOS. You need provide a fallback in the `barcodes` array, otherwise it will not show up on watch.

This is what docs are saying:

> Note that the PKBarcodeFormatQR, PKBarcodeFormatPDF417,
>   PKBarcodeFormatAztec, and PKBarcodeFormatCode128 formats are all valid
>   on iOS 9 and later; therefore, they do not need fallbacks. watchOS
>   does not support the PKBarcodeFormatCode128 format. If a
>   PKBarcodeFormatCode128 barcode is included in the barcodes array, an
>   alternative barcode is used as fallback; if a PKBarcodeFormatCode128
>   barcode is the only barcode you supply, no barcode is displayed.

Reffer to: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html